# Send Multiple Values from javascript function to PHP page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

here is the sample code.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="phpPage.php" method="POST">
  <!--5 diff values in form1 . . . -->
  <input id="b1" onclick="functionOne();">
</form>
<form id="form2" name="form2" action="phpPage.php" method="POST">
  <!-- 5 diff values in form2 . . . -->
  <input id="b2" onclick="functionTwo();">
</form>
```

i have up to 8 forms.

The problem is when I click the button `b5`, after all the validation checks have performed, I want it so it sends all values from `form1`-`form5`. I have collected the values in JS function (`functionFive()`;) through jQuery. How can I send these values to the `phpPage.php` ?

Remembering that we have fired the `onclick` event on `b5` and, as the result, the `functionFive` has been called for validation checks. How do I send the values from here to php page?

Comment: Do all these forms have the same input names? (.e.g `form1` has `foo` and `form2` has `foo`, too?

Comment: Why do you have multiple forms?

Comment: @Brad , they have different input names and values as well.

Comment: @BlakePlumb, i have such a page where user can either add 1 item detail or 2 items detail or upto 8 items detail. so for each item, i have 1 form. If it selects 7 items, obviously i have to fetch the values of the previous 6 items detail. i get them in JS function, but could not push it to php page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to use ONE FORM that encompasses all the values.

Comment: this would be worst case for me, i have developed the whole application using multiple forms :(

Comment: You could write some JavaScript to collect all of the values and submit them into a hidden form, but in the long run that may not be the best way.

Comment: +1) atleast your comment should be enuff for him to accept this answer. But all values in one form would be the better way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ajax?

```
var formData = {
    firstName: 'Dennis',
    lastName: 'Martinez'    
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'SOMEFILE.php',
    data: formData,
    success: function(e) {
        alert('success!');
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert('there was an error!');
    }
});
```

Comment: I would really go with @Diodeus answer, that is the proper way to do a form. If you really are using the above method to accomplish this please read the ajax documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.